# "Validation error. error C00CE014: App manifest validation error" when trying to create app packages for Windows Store

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I'm struggling with this error for a few hours now. I can build and deploy the app without issues, it just won't create distributable packages (Project > Store > Create App Packages)

The problem is rather weird. Here's my Package.appxmanifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:uap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap3">
  <Identity Name="481f1dca-fa19-4642-8e95-9208a4c9265f" Publisher="CN=mrrey" Version="1.1.8.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="06509575-8d8e-4beb-aa84-4ea390365781" PhonePublisherId="06509575-8d8e-4beb-aa84-4ea390365785" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>XYZ MusicBox</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>mrrey</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="XYZ_MusicBox.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="XYZ MusicBox" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="XYZ MusicBox" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
    <uap3:Capability Name="backgroundMediaPlayback" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

This is the initial state of my manifest. After I click `Create` in the wizard, it starts building the packages. The output:

```
...
1>     1018 ms  Csc                                        2 calls
1>     1091 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                   1 calls
1>     3498 ms  CompileXaml                                2 calls
1>     3615 ms  GenerateAppxManifest                       1 calls
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:11.30
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Package: 0 succeeded, 1 failed ===========
========== App Bundle: 0 succeeded, 1 failed ===========
```

After that, when I try to open the `Package.appxmanifest` file the designer doesn't want to load due to the compiler error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Validation error. error C00CE014: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 34, Column 6, Reason: Element 'Capability' is unexpected according to content model of parent element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Capabilities'. Expecting: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}CapabilityChoice, {http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}DeviceCapability. XYZ MusicBox    C:\Users\mrrey\Box Sync\XYZ MusicBox\XYZ MusicBox\bin\x86\Debug\AppxManifest.xml
```

The weirdest part of it all is the fact that during creating the package VS is modifying my original `appxmanifest` file and adding this line to the capabilities:

```
<Capability Name="backgroundMediaPlayback" xmlns="" />
```

As you can see in the code above, I already have this capability added, but it requires a `uap3:` namespace to work correctly. For some reason it still forces this one, though. And what's with that xmlns attribute with an empty value?

After attempting packages creation I'm also getting a number of warnings like this one:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Imported schema for namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities/3' was not resolved.  XYZ MusicBox    C:\Users\mrrey\Box Sync\XYZ MusicBox\XYZ MusicBox\Package.appxmanifest  17
```

Everything works correctly when I remove the original `Background Media Playback` capability, but that's not something I can afford since it's a media player app.There's clearly something wrong with this capability/project's configuration but I can't find it.

This doesn't happen when I just build the solution and deploy the app to `Local Machine`/`Device`/Emulators.

I'm using up-to-date Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10 (Version 10.0.14393 Build 14393).

Did anyone encounter a similar issue? Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Thank you!

Edit: To make things even clearer: these short warnings (Imported schema for namespace...) are referring to `<Applications>`, `<Application>`, `<Properties>` and `<Dependencies>` tags.

Edit2: [I don't even wanna think about this anymore.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1aAw.jpg) Somehow I broke it even more.

Comment: What version of W10 is your app targeting?

Comment: @MarianDolinský Both Minimum and Target version is set to Anniversary Update.